# Android, Kotlin: How to close BottomSheetDialogFragment after activity is closed without using Navigation Components?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

Background: In my application, I have a `Fragment` (A) which contains a list of **Accounts**. When any **Account** is clicked, a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` (B) opens, where you can see a list of options. If **Edit** option clicked, a new `Activity` (C) opens.

[image: A]

[image: V]

[image: C]

My issues is: when the last Activity (C) is closed, I'm navigated back to the BottomSheetDialogFragment (B) instead of Fragment (A). How can I go from (C) to (A), when (C) is closed, without using Navigation Component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When edit option is clicked you can call [dismiss](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetDialogFragment#dismiss()) method of BottomSheetDialogFragment to finish the dialog.

Comment: Thanks for a concise answer~